# Using date to get tomorrows date in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to write a bash script that will run on a given but process data with next days date, My current approach is to get the unix time stamp and add a days worth of seconds to it, but I cant get it working, and haven't yet found what I'm looking for online.

Here's what I've tried, I feel like the problem is that its a string an not a number, but I dont know enough about bash to be sure, is this correct? and how do I resolve this?

```
today="$(date +'%s')"

tomorrow="$($today + 86400)"

echo "$today"

echo "$tomorrow"
```

Comment: Would `date -d 'tomorrow' '+%s'` be sufficient?

Comment: @TomFenech I think thats the best solution.If OP want's to do it the way they are though they could use `((tomorrow=today + 86400))`

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html if you want to do it your way.
tomorrow=$(($today + 86400))

Comment: @TomFenech I actually used `'tomorrow' '+%Y-%m-%d'` in a cron job once a day at 23:30, to save data in a file with the next day's date in its name.  It went wrong last month, due to the start of daylight-savings time: 2020-03-28 23:30 +24h (which is what 'tomorrow' means) = 2020-03-30.  I'm using `'12:00 today +1days'` now, following [this FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#The-date-command-is-not-working-right_002e).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$(...)` is command substitution. You're trying to run `$today + 86400` as a command.

`$((...))` is arithmetic expansion. This is what you want to use.

```
tomorrow=$(( today + 86400 ))
```

Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression for more on doing arithmetics in the shell.

Comment: Using `$(expr $today + 86400)` would likely work as well, but this is a base-specific question so `$((...))` should be valid. Using `expr` might be better depending upon the types of environments you need to operate in.

Answer (score 20):

If you have `gnu-date` then to get next day you can just do:

```
date -d '+1 day'
```

Answer (score 14):

Some of the answers for this question depend on having GNU date installed.  If you don't have GNU date, you can use the built-in `date` command with the `-v` option.

The command

`$ date -v+1d`

returns tomorrow's date.

You can use it with all the standard `date` formatting options, so

`$ date -v+1d +%Y-%m-%d`

returns tomorrow's date in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: I ended up using `date --date="tomorrow" +%d 2>&1 | date -v +1d +%d` for any case :)

Answer (score 3):

I hope that this will solve your problem [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-get-yesterdays-tomorrows-date.html).

```
 date --date 'next day'
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your timezone, then run `date`.

E.g.

```
TZ=UTC-24 date
```

Alternatively, I'd use perl:

```
perl -e 'print localtime(time+84600)."\n"'
```

Comment: No need for the subshell and `export` - `TZ=UTC-24 date` is sufficient.

Comment: Ah yes. Tried it with a semicolon, and it failed. But none is needed is it?

Comment: With a semicolon, the assignment and command are two separate statements. Without it, the environment variable is set for the duration of the command, which is exactly what you want here.

Comment: for bash no need to set timezone but can get date in timezone using `date -u +%F` (%F is just format specifier, -u is the UTC timezone switch). Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413016/56583

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $(date --date="next day" +%Y%m%d)
```

This will output

> 20170623

Answer (score 0):

I like

```
input_date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
tomorrow_date=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d "$input_date + 1 day")
echo "$tomorrow_date"
```

It returns the date of the day after `$input_date`, in format YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0):

## `date -d '12:00 today + 1 day'`

Following @astrofloyd's lead here, and given the fact that today is the one day per year that this is relevant (but that's still a pretty big edge case), you want the above rather than merely `date -d tomorrow`, as "`tomorrow`" [is implemented as "now + 24 hours"](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html#The-date-command-is-not-working-right_002e) which could actually be two calendar date digits from now if there are 23 hours in the next calendar date digit, as it is where and when I'm sitting now:

```bash
❯ date -d today ; date -d tomorrow; date -d '12:00 today +1 day'
Sat Mar 11 23:53:29 PST 2023  # reference
Mon Mar 13 00:53:29 PDT 2023  # what??
Sun Mar 12 12:00:00 PDT 2023  # correct!
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try below

```
#!/bin/bash
today=`date`
tomorrow=`date --date="next day"`
echo "$today"
echo "$tomorrow"
```